# How to get url from c# including angular route

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, webforms

I am creating an SPA on a .aspx page. What I want to achieve is:

1. When pressing F5, I need the angular route to persist
2. On a click server event, I want to redirect(or transfer) to the same page, including the angular route

Is this possible?. If not, Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

You have to:

1. Add generic route on server, which will match all possible angular routes. As the response always return "Home" page, but don't redirect, keep the same angular URL.
2. After "Home" page is returned angular will detect route from url and display correct page.